# Save test log to disk?

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    mochaTest: {
      test: {

        options: {
          reporter: 'spec',
          clearRequireCache: true,
          require: ['./index.js']
        },
        src: ['test/**/*.coffee']
      },
      report: {

        options: {
          reporter: 'markdown',
          clearRequireCache: true,
          require: ['./index.js']
        },
        src: ['test/**/*.coffee'],
        dest: './FEATURES.md'
      }

    },
    watch: {
      test: {
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
        files: ['src/**/*.coffee', 'test/**/*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:main', 'mochaTest']
      }
    },
    coffee: {

      main: {
        options: {
          bare: true
        },

        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: "./src",
          src: ["**/*.coffee"],
          dest: "./lib",
          ext: ".js"
        }]
      },


    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee:main', 'mochaTest:test', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['coffee:main', 'mochaTest:test']);
  grunt.registerTask('report', ['coffee:main', 'mochaTest:report']);

};
```

When I run `grunt` it test and watches with report as spec, but when I run `grunt report` it show me the output in markdown although no file is created at the root of the project. And is it possible to make the markdown reporter output coffeescript in code tags instead of js? And is there a way to remove any logged output by y code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[grunt-mocha-test](https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test)** plugin does not have a **dest** option. I think you're looking for **captureFile**.

To remove all the output from the console, you can set **quiet** to true.

Here is your updated `mochaTest:report` :

```
report: {
  options: {
    reporter: 'markdown',
    clearRequireCache: true,
    require: ['./index.js'],
    quiet: true,
    captureFile: 'FEATURES.md'
  },
  src: ['test/**/*.coffee']
}
```

For your 2nd question, you can review the list of all the mocha reporters [here](http://sionmedia.github.io/mocha/#reporters) and a more concise list [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/tree/master/lib/reporters), but there is no coffee one yet.

Comment: Thank you very much.A lmast question. is there a way to output coffee?*

Comment: You want to output `coffee` instead of `markdown` with **mochaTest** or is this something else you want to achieve ?

Comment: The output code between GH fenced code is in js. I'd like it in  coffee :)

Comment: Like I said, there is no reporter for coffee yet. You can look at something like [grunt-js2coffe](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/grunt-js2coffee) but since the `js` code is wrapped inside the markdown it may be difficult to convert it. Still it's another question I think :)

Comment: Yeah, the js code inside the markdown. You should try to see the output of [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/markdown.js#L82) and convert it to create your own reporter.